# CSS won't apply to an ID only to its child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following code I am applying a style to

```
<div id="headingGroup">
    <h2>Some Heading</h2>
    <h2>Some Heading</h2>
    <h2>Some Heading</h2>
</div>
```

I would like to apply a font weight and size to all 3 headings, I thought that if the div was given an id I could call the id in CSS and apply the style to all three as follows

```
#headingGroup{
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

However the h2's do not change, however if I call the h2 directly as follows the font changes

```
#headingGroup h2{
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

Then the style is applied and the fonts change, why isn't it possible to style based on the id?

Here is what I see when I inspect element in Chrome

[image]

It appears the h2 type is overriding it?  Aren't id's more specific and should override the style applied to h2's in general?

Comment: This should works... But if `h2` have style, they will be stronger than parent id style. Do something is defined for `font-weight` or `font-size` on the Dev console when you select a `h2` ?

Comment: Agreed with @Arthur, with the two first code samples you provided, it should work. Is there any other overriding classes involved?

Comment: As I say before your update, Your problem isn't because of ID, but because browser apply a default style on `h2` and this style is stronger than parent selector (the id, or a class, ...)

Answer (score 2):

What's happening in your first snippet is the `#headingGroup` styles are being overridden by the base `h2` styles of the browser.

But, it is generally not best practice to use IDs, or even root elements, for CSS. The reason being that it becomes much harder to control the cascade, override your styles later, or reuse your styles.

Instead, make a class that you can apply *directly* to your `h2` elements and reuse elsewhere, like so:

CSS:

```
.sub-heading {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="heading-group">
  <h2 class="sub-heading">Some Heading</h2>
</div>
```

If you prefer a single class on a top-level container, you'll need to apply specificity and style the `h2`, the same way you are doing in your second example. But using a class is still preferable to styling against your ID. Think about how you may want the same styles applied to another block later! For example:

CSS:

```
.heading-group h2 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="heading-group-1" class="heading-group">
  <h2>Heading for group 1</h2>
</div>

<div id="heading-group-2" class="heading-group">
  <h2>Heading for group 2</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: No, ID are fully valid and acceptable, read my answer and try codes on it to see you'll have NO problem to use ID.

Comment: Arthur, with all due respect, while it's *possible* to style using an ID, it is generally frowned upon. IDs must be unique to a page and are best suited for targeting individual elements (such as adding functionality with JavaScript). Strive for better reusability, and stick with classes for DRYer code.

Comment: Yes.. ID must be unique and ... ?? It's not the subject in this question and your answer isn't replying to the problem but "you can use class instead of id".. ID **must** be unique but can be used to a unique part of your website (example, layout, nav bar, etc..) and **should works** (even if you think frowned upon). Also I you knew about [CSS strength](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) you know that ID can have special usage in CSS too.

Comment: Sorry, but I definitely know all about CSS specificity and the issues therein. It's precisely why I'd recommend *against* using an ID for styling except in extremely unusual cases, the same way I'd recommend against using inline styles or `!important` declarations. Just because you *can* do something, doesn't mean that you *should*.

Comment: Just to close this. The rule about id is must be unique on HTML, fine (and that's all). But this is not the question ( CSS won't apply to an ID only to its child), and the solution isn't "you should use `.heading-group h2`" (you're not answering here).. Second point, if styling ID (or using !important) was useless it was deprecated since long ago, and it's not. Because it's useful, and not recommend for beginner to avoid problems ("use only classes and you'll have no problem") But you know, Bootstrap have more than 1000 `!important` declarations.

Comment: (and i'm **not** saying here that ID should be use for re-usable component, or !important to quick fix a problem)

Comment: There's never going to be a single solution in code. But I feel it's important to caveat our answers here in a way that helps lead others to better practices. Whether or not one should use an ID or a class can be very confusing to new developers. I think my answer both explains the issue (the ID declaration does not override base HTML styles) and offers a suggested alternative that achieves the OP's core goals in a more reusable/industry-standard way. Not sure why you're taking issue with that. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** As predicted on comment before your update your browser add some style by default to h2. Exactly like if you have this on top of your CSS code:

```
h2 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-block-start: 0.83em;
    margin-block-end: 0.83em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

---

Let's  decompose your problem. CSS mean `Cascading Style Sheets` So all style you apply on a selector (here an id) is apply to all his children.
**BUT** you must know that the applied style is always the stronger one. [[More to read here]](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Let's try some example with color update to have a better visual

#### 1: Put style on parent is working good:

```css
#headingGroup {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="headingGroup">
  <h2>Some Heading</h2>
  <p>I'm not a title</p>
</div>
```

#### 2: Parent style is wicker than current object style

```css
#headingGroup {
  color: red;
}
h2 {
  color: green; /* This will over pass the color red */
}
```

```html
<div id="headingGroup">
  <h2>Some Heading</h2>
  <p>I'm not a title</p>
</div>
```

#### 3. To bypass the style default style on `h2` you have to put more Strength:

```css
#headingGroup {
  color: red; /* Text inside headingGroup is red by default */
}
h2 {
  color: green; /* This will over pass the color red */
}
#headingGroup h2 {
  color: blue; /* This will overpass all color for h2 inside the group */
}
```

```html
<p>I'm a text without style</p>
<h2>I'm not on headingGroup</h2>
<div id="headingGroup">
  <h2>Some Heading</h2>
  <p>I'm not a title</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is technically accurate in terms of explaining the hierarchy of IDs, nesting, and base classes. But by still recommending using an ID instead of a class, you'll be stuck with having a single set of styles that can only be applied to a single element on the page. Every time you create a new heading group element on the same page, you'll need to create a new ID and new styles.

Comment: I agree, but this is not the subject of the question.

Answer (score -2):

you are using `id_selectorthis`  id selector is used to select one unique element! To select an element with a specific id, write a hash (#) character, followed by the id of the element.

one is working as you specify that apply change on `h2` which is a part of 
div having `id #headingGroup`

```
 #headingGroup h2{
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 3rem;
```

}

Comment: Very unclear what you are trying to say, seems to be the same conclusion that the original poster reached to.

Comment: No no and no ! CSS is `Cascading Style Sheets` !!! So style will be also used for any children

Comment: It is usually a better practice to use classes for styling over IDs to promote reuse and to avoid over-specificity.

Answer (score -5):

Add class instead of id. Then define css for this class

Comment: No. Just no. This will change nothing (except to lower the strength of the assignment but in this case... No!)

Comment: If check your css link or src... Is it external css